# How access to Storage-Property in c#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping

I mapped some access-tables to classes. I created properties and bound them to columns. I used the Storage-property like the following

```
string _ColValue;
[Column(Storage = "_ColValue")]
public string ColValue
{
    get { return _ColValue; }
    set { _ColValue = value; }
}
```

The columns contains string values but they have many spaces at the end. They come always with a constant length. Now I want to trim the values to remove the spaces. I thougt it would be nice to manipulate the string directly while mapping from the datatable to my properties.

My intesion was to iterate all private fields of mapped properties in a method i call in the constructor.

```
void TrimPropValues()
{
    FieldInfo[] fi = this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic
                                                 | BindingFlags.Instance);

    foreach (FieldInfo fiItem in fi)
    {               
        if (fiItem.FieldType.Equals(typeof(string))
            && fiItem.GetValue(this) != null)
        {
            fiItem.SetValue(this, fiItem.GetValue(this).ToString().TrimEnd(' '));
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the method in the constructor, the fields are not filled. The mapping seems happen later. What is the right moment to call the method? When does the mapping happen or rather how can I reach the moment of mapping?

Comment: Calling this function in the constructor is definitely too early, and it happens at some internal point.  Generally a better approach is to trim values before updating to the database, or possibly loading the UI...

Comment: I make no updates, it´s only a reading db-connection

Comment: Then you'd have to manually invoke the process sometime after the query occurs; the other approach you could take is update the T4 template that EF uses and trim the text in the setter for string properties...  not easy, but doable.

Comment: Your first proposal is not especially smart, but I do it so at the moment ;-). IMHO the class itself should implement this.

Comment: Your second proposal seems to be nice, but I don´t have an IDE, that supports templates an much code generation. So it could be (too) much coding for me. It´s only a little application; it is not worth the effort. I hoped for an easier way

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate this nicely in the context subclass itself:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
        : base()
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += (sender, e) =>
        {
            TrimStringValues(Entry(e.Entity));
        };
    }

    void TrimStringValues(DbEntityEntry entry)
    {
        foreach (var property in entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames)
        {
            var currentValue = entry.CurrentValues[property] as string;
            if (currentValue != null)
                entry.CurrentValues[property] = currentValue.Trim();
        }
    }
}
```

In the context's constructor the underlying `ObjectContext`'s `ObjectMaterialized` event is subscribed to. In the event handler, each materialized entity is subjected to the `TrimStringValues` method. In this method, EF's own infrastructure is used to trim string values. This is faster than doing the same by reflection.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That´s exactly what I´m looking for.